# Serve a html page based on a url

Tags: javascript, node.js

im trying to do something with node, basicly i created the server, and now based on the url i want to get the html page, i created some html pages on my project, i need to return the html page.

**i did this**

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var fs = require("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function(request,response){

    var result = url.parse(request.url,true);
    var path = result.pathname;

    fs.readFile(path,function(err,data){
        if(err){
            return console.log("fail");
        }
        console.log(data);
    })


    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    console.log(path);

    response.end();
})

server.listen(3000);
console.log("servidor em execução");
```

it kinda fails, the fs.readfile enters in the error, i dont know very well what i am doing wrong and how to fix this, can you guys give me a little help, thanks a lot

Comment: debugging hint: `console.log(path)` before you attempt to `readFile` - is it what you expect - `console.log(err);` in the if(err) block to see what the error is - because "fail" tells you nothing

Comment: instead of `console.log("fail")` maybe do `console.log(err)` so you can see what the error is?

Comment: well i get no such file or directory error, i dont know why it search globally and not in my working directory :S

Answer (score 0):

You should try with dirname

```
if(requestUrl.endsWith('index.html'))
{
    data=fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../html/index.html', 'utf-8')
                           |           |    |
                           |           |    v
                           |           v   html folder and file
                           v         cd..(move 1 level up)
                           the directory of current js file(your main js file)
}
```

used sync version for simplicity of course you use async version as it is nodejs  friendly and performance aware. You shouldn't put requests from clients directly into fs or database commands.

Answer (score 0):

`result.pathname` would always give you path without the domain e.g. if requested url is 'http://localhost:1337/mycustomFolder/myfile.html' then `pathname` would give you '/mycustomFolder/myfile.html' and `fs.readfile(path...` would always append this with the root directory mapped to domain directory which in my case because it's C:\ because i'm running node.js on my local through a command prompt. So final path became C:\mycustomFolder\myfile.html

you can update this relative path with any directory you want if current directory is not the one you are looking for and make an absolute path before passing it to `readfile` function, see the example below. you can also use ..\ any number of time if you want to point to any parent directory

```
console.log('Starting server');
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function (req, res){
    var result = url.parse(req.url,true);
    var path = result.pathname;
    path = 'C:\\Projects' + path;
console.log(path);
    fs.readFile(path,function(err,data){
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        }
        else
        console.log(data);
    })


    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    console.log(path);

    res.end();
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server started at port 1337');
```